# Titanium Studio license

Tags: android, ios, titanium, licensing, appcelerator

I want to build my own mobile app and cross-develop for Android and iOs. Since most of the other Frameworks aren't free or use a WebView (tell me if I am wrong), which I don't want to use because I read about bad performance and not-so-nice integration into the System, I wanted to try Titanium.

So while installing and setting up I came across this one: http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/142516/warning-licensing-of-titanium-chaotic-and-unclear-how-to-avoid-extortionate-fees here. I really don't understand out of the answer: Am I or am I not allowed to write a commercial App with Titanium Studio without buying something?

On this site it seems pretty clear that it is free and only the extra services (cloud and stuff) cost something: http://www.appcelerator.com/plans-pricing/

I don't need a cloud or any infrastructure of Appcelerator I think.

So is it free to develop commercial apps or not? And if I understand right and the extra services are the only thing that cost something, is there a commercial feature/service which I will have to use any way for most apps?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139804/can-licensing-questions-ever-be-on-topic) for details, and the [help] for more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I remember when this all came about.

It is free, unless you want those additional services.  I never ran into the issue myself, but my understanding is that there was a lot of confusion around the licensing which was simplified.  Soon after that situation, another blog post, which I can't seem to find, where they changed the licensing and made it simpler.

This was the response to your forum reference:
http://www.appcelerator.com/blog/2012/10/please-review-proposed-license-agreement-changes/

http://www.appcelerator.com/legal/appexplore-agreement/

> Titanium Studio at the App Explore level is a free closed-­‐source
>   commercial product subject to the terms herein. Use of Studio under
>   App Explore is provided absolutely free of charge. Use of the
>   Appcelerator Analytics and/or Appcelerator Cloud Services is free up
>   to a certain tier found at http://www.appcelerator.com/plans-­pricing.
>   You may incur fees or have certain usage disabled or reduced for usage
>   beyond the free App Explore tier as set forth on the Appcelerator
>   website. No support or other services will be available from
>   Appcelerator under the terms of this Agreement at the App Explore
>   level.

You can use it for free.

Comment: Do I understand it right that using the Alloy MVC Framework is free too? And can you tell me what the App Explore level is? I don't really get it :/

Comment: Alloy is just their MVC framework, so that should be fine as well.  On the App Explore level, I think that was what the cloud services were called before they changed them.  I guessing at that.  It looks like the pricing and plans section has been changed.